# How to Refresh. Datagridview after adding data.im using sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

below is my code for my project.
hope you can help me.
thanks in advance. :)

this is my sqlcontrol code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SQLControl

    Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SQLTest;User=sa;Pwd=xxxx;"}
    Public SQLCmd As SqlCommand 'allow us to fire query at the data base
    Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public SQLDataset As DataSet
    Public dtable As New DataTable
    Public bs As New BindingSource
    'QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            SQLCon.Close()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub ExecQuery(ByVal Query As String)
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()

            'CREATE SQL COMMAND
            SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

            'LOAD PARAMETER INTO SQL COMMAND
            Params.ForEach(Sub(x) SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(x))

            'CLEAR PARAMETER LIST
            Params.Clear()

            'EXCUTE COMMAND FILL MY DATASET
            SQLDataset = New DataSet
            'EXCUTE COMMAND WIHTOUT ADAPTER 
            SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
            RecordCount = SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)

            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = ex.Message
        End Try

        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLCon.Close()

    End Sub

    Public Sub RunQuery(ByVal Query As String)
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()

            SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

            'LOAD SQL RECORDS FOR DATAGRID
            SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
            SQLDataset = New DataSet
            SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)

            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

            If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                SQLCon.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddMember(ByVal PC As String, ByVal IP As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Email As String, ByVal Department As String, ByVal Location As String,
                     ByVal Model As String, ByVal Specs As String, ByVal Dt As String, ByVal Asset As String, ByVal Rent As String)

        Try
            Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (pc,ip,name,email,department,location,model,specs,date,asset,rent) " & _
                                 "VALUES (" & _
                                 "'" & PC & "'," & _
                                 "'" & IP & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Name & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Email & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Department & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Location & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Model & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Specs & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Dt & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Asset & "'," & _
                                 "'" & Rent & "')"
            MsgBox(strInsert)

            SQLCon.Open()
            SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)

            SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is my form code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private SQL As New SQLControl

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'EXECUTE QUERY AND POPULATE GRID
        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM members")
        LoadGrid()

        'DISABLE SAVE BUTTON
        cmdSave.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadGrid()
        'IF OUR DATA IS RETURNED AND POPULATE GRID & BUILD UPDATE COMMAND
        If SQL.RecordCount > 0 Then
            dgvData.DataSource = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
            dgvData.Rows(0).Selected = True
            SQL.SQLDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.SQLDA).GetUpdateCommand
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvData_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvData.CellValueChanged
        cmdSave.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvData_RowsRemoved(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs) Handles dgvData.RowsRemoved
        cmdSave.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
        'SAVE UPDATE TO THE DATA BASE
        Try
            SQL.SQLDA.Update(SQL.SQLDataset) ' TO DO: DATA VALIDATION
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Already Exists")
        End Try

        'REFRESH GRID DATA
        LoadGrid()

        'DISABLE SAVE BUTTON
        cmdSave.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click

        If Trim(txtPC.Text) = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill out the pc name.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Trim(txtIP.Text) = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill out the ip address.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Query for user
        SQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM members WHERE members.PC = '" & txtPC.Text & "'")

        If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("The name that you have enter enter is already exists")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        SQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM members WHERE members.IP = '" & txtIP.Text & "'")
        If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("The IP Address that you have enter is already exists!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        SQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM members WHERE members.Asset = '" & txtAsset.Text & "'")
        If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("The Asset that you have enter is already exists")
            Exit Sub
        Else

            CreateUser()
            txtPC.Clear()
            txtIP.Clear()
            txtName.Clear()
            txtEmail.Clear()
            txtDepartment.Clear()
            txtLocation.Clear()
            txtModel.Clear()
            txtSpecs.Clear()
            txtDt.Clear()
            txtAsset.Clear()
            txtRent.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub CreateUser()
        SQL.AddMember(txtPC.Text, txtIP.Text, txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtDepartment.Text,
                  txtLocation.Text, txtModel.Text, txtSpecs.Text, txtDt.Text, txtAsset.Text, txtRent.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I don't know how to refresh the `datagridview`

Comment: retrieve data from DataBase and Bind to Grid after adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will works. just
Copy And Paste this to your load form.

```
Public Sub RefreshUserGrid()
    ' RUN QUERY
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM members")
    If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        dgvData.DataSource = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
        dgvData.Rows(0).Selected = True
    End If

End Sub
```

and also copy and paste this RefreshUserGrid() at your add command.